# Selecting all the rows with maximum occurance (if there is more than one, show them all)

Tags: mysql, max

I have a table emp with empid and reviewid:

```
CREATE TABLE 'emp' (
   'empid' INT NOT NULL,
   'reviewid' INT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ('empid'));


INSERT INTO 'emp' ('empid', 'reviewid') VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO  'emp' ('empid', 'reviewid') VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO 'emp' ('empid', 'reviewid') VALUES ('3', '2');
INSERT INTO 'emp' ('empid', 'reviewid') VALUES ('4', '2');
INSERT INTO 'emp' ('empid', 'reviewid') VALUES ('5', '3');
INSERT INTO 'emp' ('empid', 'reviewid') VALUES ('6', '4');
```

I want to select the reviews with the most number of occurrence, and more importantly (the part that I don't know how to do) is to show all the rows with maximum occurrence when there is a tie. So in the example above, the result should be reviewid 1 and 2 (since they both occur twice).

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| reviewid                                            |
|   1                                                 |
|   2                                                 |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `GROUP BY reviewid`, then `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`?

Comment: I did that but my problem was showing the multiple results when there is a tie.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT reviewid FROM emp GROUP BY reviewid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try ...

```
SELECT reviewid FROM emp GROUP BY reviewid HAVING COUNT(*) =
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp GROUP BY reviewid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: @H A - this should give you exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was seeking. Just a quick question, doesn't `LIMIT 1` limit the output to the top row only? I am asking because I thought of this solution then I thought that this will not give me all the candidates.

Comment: @H_A the limit 1 returns the highest count in the subquery, the main query then returns ALL records matching that count ;-)  - Try it on your data

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with an aggregation results in a rather cumbersome query:

```
select reviewid, count(*)
from emp
group by reviewid
having count(*) = (select max(cnt)
                   from (select reviewid, count(*) as cnt
                         from emp
                         group by reviewid
                        ) r
                  );
```

If you want the details, you would then join in the original rows.

Comment: Your suggested code produced the following error: Unknown column 'cnt' in 'field list'. I am running the code on MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote?  This answer is correct and is a very reasonable way to get the desired result (and the accepted answer is another reasonable way).  Anonymous downvotes are irritating.

Comment: I didn't downvote sorry there must have been someone else who did so.